# Visual Studio 2008, error c2039: 'set_new_handler' : is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

So the other day I went to compile a VC++ project I am working on and all of a sudden I get errors in almost all of my files saying:

> new.h: error C2039: 'set_new_handler' : is not a member of 'std
>   new.h: error C2039: 'set_new_handelr' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration

"new.h" and 'set_new_handler' are not being used in any of my files, so I have no idea how or why these errors are suddenly appearing since they relate to a windows/VS library file.

Would anyone know what I can do to clear this error and compile my code again?

**UPDATE** After examining the files being included upon compilation, some files are including  and some are . The problem is that  is being included in afxwin.h and  is being included in a third-party library. I honestly have no idea what to do with this problem...no other developers that have played with this code are running into this problem, may it be a settings problem? I am not using precompiled headers.

Comment: that is normally found in <new>, is *that* being included anywhere?

Comment: also, you say it is happening in nearly all of your files. Have you looked at any pre-compiled headers you may be using?

Comment: i am not using any precompiled headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were to hazard a guess, I would say that `<new.h>` declares `set_new_handler` in the global namespace and `<new>` declares it within the `std` namespace. Some code is including `<new.h>` and expecting it to act as if it had included `<new>`. I would suspect either some 3rd party library/header or a precompiled header as suggested by Evan.

You can narrow down the culprit using either `/showIncludes` or pre-processing a source code file (using `/E`) and examining the output. I usually use the latter and look at the `#line` directives in the output file to figure out the include chain.

Good luck.